# How to Make Organization Chart dynamic

Tags: html, css

There's a neat responsive org chart layout on codepen here: http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/* Generic styling */

body {
  background: #F5EEC9;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1142px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
a:focus {
  outline: 2px dashed #f7f7f7;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .content {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul a {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: .7em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: -26px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all linear .1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear .1s;
  transition: all linear .1s;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  ul a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
ul a span {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.7em;
  display: block;
}
/*
 
 */

.administration > li > a {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.director > li > a {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}
.subdirector:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 130px;
  background: red;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  left: 45.45%;
  position: relative;
}
.subdirector,
.departments {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.subdirector > li:first-child,
.departments > li:first-child {
  width: 18.59894921190893%;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 0 auto 92px auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.subdirector > li:first-child {
  float: right;
  right: 27.2%;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
}
.departments > li:first-child {
  float: left;
  left: 27.2%;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
}
.subdirector > li:first-child a,
.departments > li:first-child a {
  width: 100%;
}
.subdirector > li:first-child a {
  left: 25px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .subdirector > li:first-child,
  .departments > li:first-child {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .subdirector > li:first-child {
    right: 10%;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
  .subdirector:after {
    left: 49.8%;
  }
  .departments > li:first-child {
    left: 10%;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
}
.departments > li:first-child a {
  right: 25px;
}
.department:first-child,
.departments li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 0;
  clear: left;
}
.departments:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 81.1%;
  height: 22px;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
  border-right: 4px solid #fff;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 130px;
  left: 9.1%
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .departments:after {
    border-right: none;
    left: 0;
    width: 49.8%;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .department:first-child:before,
  .department:last-child:before {
    border: none;
  }
}
.department:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 22px;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -22px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.department {
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  width: 18.59894921190893%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1.751313485113835%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.lt-ie8 .department {
  width: 18.25%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .department {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .department:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 60px;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -60px;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: -4px;
  }
  .department:nth-child(2):before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.department > a {
  margin: 0 0 -26px -4px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.department > a:hover {
  height: 80px;
}
.department > ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.department li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  height: 80px;
}
.department li a {
  background: #fff;
  top: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 90%;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  right: -1px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjAlIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjMDAwMDAwIiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMjUiLz4KICAgIDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwMDAwMCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwIi8+CiAgPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KICA8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2dyYWQtdWNnZy1nZW5lcmF0ZWQpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) !important;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)))!important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)!important;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)!important;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)!important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)!important;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#40000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}
.department li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 80px;
  width: 95%;
  top: 39px;
  background-image: none!important;
}
/* Department/ section colors */

.department.dep-a a {
  background: #FFD600;
}
.department.dep-b a {
  background: #AAD4E7;
}
.department.dep-c a {
  background: #FDB0FD;
}
.department.dep-d a {
  background: #A3A2A2;
}
.department.dep-e a {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Responsive Organization Chart</h1>
  <figure class="org-chart cf">
    <ul class="administration">
      <li>
        <ul class="director">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span>Director</span></a>
            <ul class="subdirector">
              <li><a href="#"><span>Assistante Director</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="departments cf">
              <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span></a>
              </li>

              <li class="department dep-a">
                <a href="#"><span>Department A</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A1</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A2</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A3</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A4</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A5</span></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-b">
                <a href="#"><span>Department B</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B1</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B2</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B3</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B4</span></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-c">
                <a href="#"><span>Department C</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C1</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C2</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C3</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C4</span></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-d">
                <a href="#"><span>Department D</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D1</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D2</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D3</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D4</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D5</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D6</span></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="department dep-e">
                <a href="#"><span>Department E</span></a>
                <ul class="sections">
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </figure>
</div>
```

However when you remove one of the departments from the markup the layout doesn't gets adjusted. I'd like to know how it can done.

Comment: Good ideia (!). Well, for solve your problem... Perhaps another approach, using a web-based construction tool and linking or copy/pasting a state for your page?  See http://www.cogmap.com/

Comment: Web-based tools can solve my problem, but i want to know whether it can be done programmatically and any suggestions for achieving it.

Comment: Do you two know each other? ... [Make organization chart by HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42920694/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

use this jQuery plugin  , this is very professional.
http://www.jointjs.com/

Comment: ya this plugin is useful if you know all the entities at design time, i'd like to know whether it can be done programmatically through javascript or some additional CSS code.

Comment: i don't understand why you want to do with javascript . but i guess may you don't search enough. http://www.jointjs.com/demos/org , http://www.jointjs.com/js/org.js . create flexible chart with javascript and CSS need to a lot of time spend . are you need to ajax load data or somethings like that ?

Comment: yeah u are right i need to display chart using dynamic data and it needs to be responsive, which the mentioned code snippet satisfies.

Comment: well , you can write simple jQuery plug in based on joint . in fact you should create instance of joint onSuccess of ajax call and ajax call for add and remove . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638948/extremely-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial .

Comment: i have seen the demos of JointJS i think it's great, but i think they are not responsive. do u have know any other which are responsive and support ajax data load.

Comment: check https://github.com/goinnn/jquery.graphviz jquery.graphviz